# Given an array, and a series of queries for indices `i j` how do I find out which index has been queried the most number of times efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array `A`, indexed from `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the size of the array, and a series of queries of the form `i j` where `i` and `j` indicate indices (`i` and `j` inclusive), how do I find out which index has been queries the most number of times efficiently?

For example, consider an array `[3,4,5,6,7,9]`

And queries

```
0 3
3 5
1 2
2 4

Output
Index 0 has been queried 1 time.
Index 1 has been queried 2 times.
Index 2 has been queried 3 times.
Index 3 has been queried 3 times.
Index 4 has been queried 2 times.
Index 5 has been queried 1 time.
```

How do I make this as fast as possible?

Comment: I see 1 access for 0, 1 for 1, 2 for 2, 2 for 3, 1 for 4, 1 for 5 as times each one is referenced. Or are they counted somehow differently?

Comment: 0 3 accesses all elements in the interval [0,3], 0 and 3 inclusive. Counting accesses that way, we get the output given above.

Comment: Please edit your question to say this explicitly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in O(n+q) where n is size of array and q is the number of queries by:

1. Make empty array A with n entries
2. For each query i,j increase A[i] by 1 and decrease A[j+1] by 1
3. Loop over the array computing the cumulative total and keep track of the index with the highest cumulative total

The cumulative total will contain +1 for each interval where we have seen the start, and -1 for each interval where we have seen the end.  This means that the total will give the count of current open intervals, or in other words the number of times that entry has been queried.

Comment: That's probably the best solution. I didn't understand what you meant by "pick element with the highest total". when looping through the array, you just print the cumulative sum until that entry, no?

Comment: @RonTeller all I was trying to communicate is that you are searching for the index with the most queries, which is the same as the position of the highest cumulative sum.  I've tried to rewrite it a bit.

Comment: I found a bug :P You should make an empty array either with n+1 entries or you should handle the limits that exactly end at n-1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) to store all your queries (construction of the tree takes `O(nlogn)` time), then check for each array entry how many intervals contain it (`O(log n)`) time.

A more naive, but still effective approach would be to use an auxiliary array `A` of size `n` (all entries initialized to 0), for each query do:

```
for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
    A[k]++;
```

And then just print the array.

Comment: The naive approach is too slow, I need to do this for over 200000 queries. I'll try to do it with an interval tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1) Sort all the times in the given queries. O(q log q)
 2) num_times_queried[times[i]]=num_queries_started_till[times[i]]-num_queries_ended_till[times[i]-1]

 num_queries_started/ended_till(x) can be found in log q using binary search.
```

O(q log q + n log q)

Answer (score 0):

There are several measures possible: Running the accesses and any processing done while at it are "free," you want to get a the count after all is done efficiently; or you need to consider the processing during access and the final search.

In the first case, set up a priority queue and bump each one up as it is accessed. The final step of getting the most accessed is constant.

In the second case, you can't do better than to count each access for each index (linear in the number of accesses) and at the end go through the counts to pick the largest (linear in the number of indices, presumably less than the number of accesses).